# libnpjp2.so - java plugin missing in openjdk-8-jdk:i386

Tags: java, openjdk, firefox-extensions, icedtea

I am using ubuntu 14.10 and i installed jdk8 via `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk:i386`. Using `update-alternatives`, I have made java 8 as the default one.

Now, when i checked java on firefox using this [link](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp), it showed java plugin is not working on browser.

To fix this, I tried to copy libnpjp2.so from `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/lib/i386` to `~/.mozilla/plugins` folder.

But i can see, the plugin `so` file is missing inside the jvm libs folder

How can i make java plugin work in firefox with openjdk-8?

Comment: Is there some reason you are using 32 bit java (on a supposedly 64 bit machine)?

Comment: Cisco's webex works only on 32 bit firefox which needs 32 bit java

Comment: The what. Java is a language designed to be independent from the running machine's architecture by using a VM. That's why any machine (or smartphone) can run a jar file if they have a java VM installed. So the 32 bits are only relevant to the host OS. I'd recommend using a java VM that actually runs on your machine before trying to combine it with Firefox.

Comment: @Wolfer, you're right. In theory. I have no idea why, but audio doesn't work with Webex on 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the icedtea-plugin:i386, it will create

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/lib/i386/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

which you can symlink to

```
~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install  icedtea-plugin

Comment: @YuJiaao I think it's `sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin:i386` on 64 bit systems.

Comment: I had to add `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/IcedTeaPlugin.so libnpjp2.so`

Comment: There is no need to link with `libnpjp2.so`, I ran `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so .` and activated IcedTea plugin by visiting https://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp

Comment: if you install java manually, you also need to make sure that the javaws binary points to the correct jdk version. in my case, i had an alternative configured that needed proper linking.